# fscanf segfault reading into an array

Tags: c

Why is fscanf in this code giving me a segfault?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  int n = atoi(argv[2]);

  char *words[n]; int i=0;
  while ((fscanf(file, "%s ", &words[i])) != EOF) i++;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `&words[i]` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't allocate memory for your words[i]. They are just pointers point to random memory addresses.

Comment: Indeed you should do char `**words = new char[n][m];`, where m is the max length you will input.

Comment: I tried with `m=20` and got `error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[20]’ to ‘char**’ in initialization`.

Comment: My fault. It should be 1. `char words[n][m];` 2. `char *words[n] = new char[n][m];` 3. `char *words[n]; for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) words[i] = new char();`

Comment: WHY IS THERE NO SYNTACTIC SUGAR FOR THAT??? When I program in Haskell or python the code flows like honey from my fingers. When I program in C++ everything is a clusterf***.

Comment: `new char` is not legal in C

Comment: The author said he used the `new` so I think he is using c++ in fact.